# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS neither plays nor downloads audio files from the internet. How can I fix this?

Tags: sound, update-manager

I've updated Ubuntu to 22.04.01 LTS and can now neither download files not play them. How can I can I fix this?

[image]

Tried to google the solution but found none.

Comment: Your title seems to have nothing to do with the body of the question. You appear to have a problem with some app called Totem. Did you verify it works with Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: I'm a bit of a dummy. But this is a message that my computer gives me everytime I'm trying to start an audiofile. Do you think it can stand on the way of an audio being played? And what can I do to work out the way out of the problem?

Comment: Totem is a media player. What kind of audio files is it? Do you have `ubuntu-restricted-addons` installed?

Comment: No, it's not found. Do I need to install is? And how can I do this?

Comment: Yes, please install it. I suppose you can search for it in the Software Center, or whatever it's now called. That package provides multimedia codecs.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing the gstreamer codecs from the add-ons section of software app. And, or `rm -r ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/`